# Discount issue?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am working on a big Drupal 7 commerce site and I have some issues with the commerce discount module on order discount. Both Drupal 7, commerce, commerce discount and rules is on newest stable releases.

When going through the checkout and a order discount is attached to the order (either with a discount code or direct) it's visible in the commerce_order_total_data field in the field_data_commerce_order_total table.

When going from checkout_review -> payment the discount is suddenly removed from this order and not getting back.

Cannot figure out what caused this neighter where it happens.

And a sitecomment here is that it works on dev and stage server, but not production (same code and every thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real way for anyone to answer this without being part of your site and debugging along side of you. The best I can do is say look into what about the production configuration might cause conditions that must be met for those order items to be created / updated to no longer apply. ‍♂️